# Why is my pivot table not generating an id column?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am developing an API with nodejs and I am using Sequelize as ORM.

I have the following many to many relationship within User and UserType.

User.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});


User.addHook('beforeCreate', async (user, options) => {
    if (user.password) {
        console.log('Original Password:', user.password);
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        console.log('Generated Salt:', salt);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
        console.log('Hashed Password:', user.password);
    }
});


   
User.prototype.getSignedJwtToken = function() {
    return jwt.sign({ id: this.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
       expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE
    });
};
   
User.prototype.matchPassword = function(enteredPassword) {
    console.log('Entered Password:', enteredPassword);
    console.log('Stored Password:', this.password);
    
    try {
        const isMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(enteredPassword.trim(), this.password.trim());
        console.log('Password Match Result:', isMatch);
        return isMatch;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in matchPassword:', error);
        return false;
    }
};



module.exports = User;
```

UserType.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');
const User = require('./User.model');

const UserType = sequelize.define('UserType', {
    id: { 
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    type: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM('House Sitter', 'Pet Sitter'),
        allowNull: false
    }
});


module.exports = UserType;
```

index.js where I stablish the relationships:

```
const User = require('./User.model');
const UserType = require('./UserType.model');

UserType.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'User_Types' });
User.belongsToMany(UserType, { through: 'User_Types' });
```

I am syncing my tables in server.js

```
sequelize.sync()
 .then(() => console.log('Users table synced'))
 .catch(error => console.error('Error while syncronizing Users table:', error));
```

By default Sequelize creates the pivot table named `user_types`

The table has `createdAt, updatedAt, userId, userTypeId` but it doesn´t have a `id` column why is this? Should I added myself somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By passing a string to through above, we are asking Sequelize to automatically generate a model named User_Profiles as the through table (also known as junction table), with only two columns: userId and profileId. A composite unique key will be established on these two columns.

ref: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/

As per documentation, by default, Sequelize will create a composite unique key on the 2 foreign keys. If you want to add additional columns including your own primary key, you need to define it yourself.